# Github contributions graph empty after job change

Tags: github, graph, profile, collaboration

I changed jobs and my beautiful green Github contributions graph is now almost completely empty. I worked on the same project every day for one year and now all my hard work looks like it's gone!

I realise this is because I was a collaborator on a private repo at my old company. When I started my new job, the old company removed me as a collaborator on their project.

I have looked through the docs on Github but it looks like that is how the graph works. Is there any way to get it back? How can I stop the same thing happening at my next job?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a lot but unable to find a fruitful solution.

From their [website](https://github.community/t5/Support-Protips/Getting-all-your-commits-in-your-contributions-graph/ba-p/19) `We recommend starring any repositories you contribute to. That way, your commits to those repositories will remain in your contributions graph even if you leave the organization that owns the repository or delete your fork of the repository.`
I have tested this approach by creating another github account and starring the repository which doesn't work as they said.

I also have gone through [this](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/best-practices-for-leaving-your-company), but this doesn't help to solve the issue.

I don't think there is any way to show contribution if owner removes collaborator.